# Problema com BindValue e PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Olá, pessoal boa tarde. Estou com problema para fazer a ligação por BindValue à minha variável, nota-se que fiz a ligação, pedi para retornar os valores com o FetchAll e ele está retornando um array vazio. Quando uso normalmente sem o bindValue ele funciona. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Código:

```
try {
    $conexao = new PDO("mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost" , "root", "");

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    $comando = $conexao ->prepare("select * from usuario where nome like '%:nome%'");

    $comando ->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
    $comando ->execute();

    $inf = $comando ->fetchAll();

    print_r($inf);

} catch (PDOException $ex){
    echo 'Erro: ' .$ex->getCode() . '<br>';
    echo 'Mensagem de erro: ' .$ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Olá, insira o código na pergunta  e não um print.  Recomendo a [leitura](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/77268)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar o seu problema você precisa colocar os porcentos na variável e não no parâmetro da instrução `SQL`, exemplo:

```
$comando = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome like :nome");
$comando->bindValue(':nome', "%{$nome}%");
```

e continue o resto como está que automaticamente a troca de parâmetro agora está no formato correto.

- [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
- [Using LIKE in bindParam for a MySQL PDO Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068230/using-like-in-bindparam-for-a-mysql-pdo-query)

Comment: Obrigado, amigo funcionou desta forma :)